# Which algorithm use to analyze an image (to find dirty point) using C or C# language?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, analyzer

I have a small project that a program used to analyze an image to find out "Is it dirty or not".
For detail, I use a camera (maybe mobile phone) to take a picture, and then I use program that I've talk above to determine where is the location that the dirty apear.
Sorry for my english, it looks like a cleaning-robot (take a picture, if that place have dirty place, so the robot clean it)
Hope you help me :)
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to make something work using [imagemagick](http://imagemagick.org/), but it sounds like you'll probably have to do something using full [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).